# If $f(x) = p \sin x + qx \cos x + x^2$ is defined for all $x,q,p \in \Bbb R$ and $f(2) = 3$ find $f(-2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm preparing for the GRE Subject Test in Mathematics and unfortunately found that can't understand the way the following problem should be done.
[image]
The right option is **D**, but I can't deduce it.

For $x=2$ we obtain $-1 = p\sin 2 + 2q\cos 2$. Since $x=-2$ is symmetrical with $x=2$ around the $y$-axis the value of sine should change its sign ($\sin 2 = -\sin (-2)$) and the value of cosine stands similar ($\cos2 = \cos(-2)$), but we still have one equation with two unknows. How should I proceed to the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$f(x)+f(-x)=(p\sin x + qx \cos x + x^2) + (p\sin(-x) + q(-x)\cos (-x) + (-x)^2\\=p\sin x + qx\cos x + x^2 - p\sin x - qx \cos x + x^2$$

Now simplify the equation (a lot of things cancel out) and plug in $x=2$.

---

An alternative would be to directly write

$$f(-2)=p\sin(-2) + -2q\cos 2 + 4 = (-p\sin(2) - 2q\cos 2 - 2^2) + 2^2 + 4 = -f(2)+8$$

Comment: Thanks. The first approach (hint) really broaden my horizon for such kind of questions.

Comment: @Hasek Happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

$$f\left( -2 \right) =p\sin { \left( -2 \right) -2q\cos { 2 } +4 } =-p\sin { 2 } -2q\cos { 2 } +4=\\ =-\left( \underset { -1 }{ \underbrace { p\sin { 2+ } 2q\cos { 2 }  }  }  \right) +4=\color{red}{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

We are given that $f(x)=u(x)+x^2$ with $u$ an odd function. From $3=f(2)=u(2)+2^2$ it follows that $u(2)=-1$, hence $f(-2)=-u(2)+(-2)^2=5$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(2)=p\sin 2+2q\cos 2+4$, while $f(-2)=-p\sin 2-2q\cos 2+4$. If $f(2)=3$, then $p\sin 2+2q\cos 2=-1$, so $f(-2)=-(-1)+4=5$.